# How to find out every single SD card that was inserted into a Mac?

Tags: sd-card

Is there any way I can find out every single SD card that was ever inserted into a Mac?

Comment: I'd be surprised if such information was kept. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect this prospectively, but not retrospectively. Here's how.

Create a folder for reports, let's say `sd-reports` in your main user folder.

Create a cron job. Use Terminal and `crontab -e`. Look up elsewhere the syntax for cron jobs.

Here is your command:

```sh
system_profiler SPCardReaderDataType > $HOME/sd-reports/$(date +\%Y\%m\%dT\%H\%M\%S.txt)
```

This will report on inserted cards at whatever frequency you desire. You'll have a lot of reports to go through and there are other ways to clean that up.

Comment: I'm so glad this doesn't "just happen". I used to get through several thousand SD cards a year, for work. My drive would be full & I'd be wondering why. +1 also for knowing the correct usage of 'prospectively' ;))